# Goroutine parallel execution confirmation

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

I'm new to goroutines, channels and the likes so apologies if this seems trivial.

I've written the following code:

```
for _, h := range hosts {

      go func() {
        httpClient := cleanhttp.DefaultPooledClient()

        // format the URL with the passed host and por
        url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s:%v", h.Name, h.Port)
        // create a vault client
        client, err := api.NewClient(&api.Config{Address: url, HttpClient: httpClient})
        if err != nil {
          panic(err)
        }
        // get the current status
        status := v.VaultStatus(client)

        // send the status to a channel
        s <- strconv.FormatBool(status.Ready)

      }()

      // assign the value of channel to a var
      cs := <-s

      // print it
      fmt.Printf("Host: %s Status:  %s\n", h.Name, cs)

    }
  },
```

The idea is simple, it takes a list of hosts and then uses the Golang Vault API to go and determine the current status. I'm happy enough that it works.

What'd I'd like to do is ensure these operations happen in parallel. When I run the following code, I get the results as follows:

```
host: Host1: status: true
host: Host2: status: false
host: Host3: status: true
host: Host4: status: true
```

The issue here is that these hosts are *always* returned in the same order. I don't think the goroutines are executing in parallel at all, as they appear to operate one after the other and then get printed in the same order every time.

Is the code doing what I think it should? How can I *know* this goroutine is operating in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only running one goroutine at a time, because the main goroutine is waiting on the channel before continuing with the next iteration of the loop. Instead, you should wait for the results on the channel outside the for loop after all the goroutines have been started. By the way, you'll need to send something identifying the host on the channel as well.

By the way, you have a potential problem in your goroutine function. You're using the variable `h`, which is being changed by the main goroutine each time through the loop, so you don't really know what you're getting in the other goroutines (assuming you take care of the problem I mentioned above so that the goroutines do run in parallel). Instead of referencing that variable directly, you should pass it as an argument to the goroutine function (or you can create a different variable inside the for loop and assign it the value of `h`and use that variable inside the function).

Try doing it like this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, h := range hosts {
    h := h // create local copy of loop var
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        httpClient := cleanhttp.DefaultPooledClient()

        // format the URL with the passed host and por
        url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s:%v", h.Name, h.Port)
        // create a vault client
        client, err := api.NewClient(&api.Config{Address: url, HttpClient: httpClient})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        // get the current status
        status := v.VaultStatus(client)

        // print it
        fmt.Printf("Host: %s Status:  %v\n", h.Name, status.Ready)

    }()
}
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: I can certainly pass it as an argument to the goroutine, I'll definitely change the code.

I added the channels because the main function was exiting before the goroutines had time to finish. What _should_ I be doing here? A playground link would be great, I only understand the concepts when I see them live visualized :(

Comment: How about if you print the status within the goroutine function? To wait for the goroutines to finish, you can use `sync.WaitGroup`. I'll put this in my answer.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for! I'm going to accept the answer, but, it would be great to get an explanation of your comment: "Instead, you should wait for the results on the channel outside the for loop after all the goroutines have been started" and how do it that way as well!

Comment: If you wait for results on the channel inside the loop, you will run in lockstep with the goroutines you create. In other words, you'll start one goroutine and wait for it to send the result on the channel before starting the next goroutine, so they will run one at a time. After the for loop, you can read the channel in a for loop that executes once for each host.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you want to know whether goroutines are operating in parallel, you should [trace the scheduler](https://www.goinggo.net/2015/02/scheduler-tracing-in-go.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a:

```
type Status struct {
  URL   string
  Ready bool
}
```

And `s` initialized as:

```
s := make(chan Status)
```

Then you could write:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, h := range hosts {
  h := h
  wg.Add(1)
  go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    httpClient := cleanhttp.DefaultPooledClient()

    // format the URL with the passed host and por
    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s:%v", h.Name, h.Port)
    // create a vault client
    client, err := api.NewClient(&api.Config{Address: url, HttpClient: httpClient})
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    // get the current status
    status := v.VaultStatus(client)

    // send the status to the channel
    s <- Status{url, status.Ready}

  }()
}
// this goroutine's job is closing s after all above goroutines have finished
go func() {
  wg.Wait()
  close(s) // so the following loop does not block after reading all statuses
}()
for st := range s {
    // here you could collect all statuses in a []Status or something
    // for simplicity, just print them as you did
    fmt.Printf("Host: %s Status: %v\n", st.URL, st.Ready)
}
```